# How to get a raise while working for 3 companies at same time?

Tags: raise, contractors

I am a remote software developer involved with 3 companies:

Company A sign my papers, pay me every month and sell my hours to Company B.

Company B gives me equipment, an office and his important name in the industry and sell my hours to Company C.

Company C is where I really perform my tasks, have a team, manager, etc.

Company C seems to like my work and already told that to Company B, but the company that really pays me is Company A.

Which company should I approach to get a raise? And how? I don't think most arguments would work in the situation because the company that can rate my work (Company C) is not same one paying me (Company A) and there is Company B between them.

The common way for other people in the same situation was Company B hiring you from Company A.

Edit: I applied to work for Company B and interviewed only with Company B and C. Company A was introduced as a partner by Company B after Company C approved my hiring.

Once I asked a raise for Company A, they forwarded my request to Company B and it was Company B that gave me the response that it was easier for them to hire me than approving a raise.

Comment: Funnily enough I just answered this question!  You tell company A, and here's exactly how to do it:  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/122980/22844

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're an employee of company A.

You ask them for a raise and negotiate anything else relating to your work contract with them.

How (if at all) they pass along this then additional cost to company B who has the client company C who actually pays for all this fun (my head is spinning) is not your concern nor any of your business.

However do read your contract in case it has anything to say about wage negotiations, possibly answering your question.

Another thing that works like a charm to raise your wage is to apply to other companies with a much higher salary expectation.
If they agree, you just raised your price.

Of course this means to uproot yourself from your current situation and may not be what you want right now.

Comment: Two great answers here !

Answer (score 8):

> but the company that really pays me is Company A.

I really don't understand why you even have to ask this question at all.

You are paid by company 'A', therefore you are employed by company 'A'. If you want to request a raise then obviously you'd make that request to company 'A'.

Approaching the other companies is unprofessional, unethical, and may well violate your agreement and/or contract with company 'A'.

Comment: Because once when I asked Company A, they forwarded the request to Company B. And also because it is common for Company B hire people from Company A when they want a raise. Also I interviewed with Company B and C. Company A was introduced only to sign the papers and pay me.

Comment: And if you are a contractor you just increase your daily / hourly rate when the contract is renewed

Comment: @Neuromancer I am sold as contractor to Company B and C, but for Company A I am an employee.

Comment: Like Steve state, company A is paying you, so you deal with them. If they forward your request to a third party, like company B, and state they cannot do anything because their forwarded your request, I will take it as a cheap tactic to decline your raise.

Comment: @SebastienDErrico perfectly explained it.  The "we spoke to company B!" thing is completely ridiculous.

Comment: I agree. This is basically the same situation as working for a garage as a mechanic. You don't ask the person who's truck you are working on for a raise. They don't ask the construction company that truck driver delivers to. You ask the garage.