# How should I ask for an increment in my salary, when the owner of the company is my friend?

Tags: communication, salary, pakistan

I have been working in a Software House of my friend for the past 3 years and still working there.

Everything is fine and job is also amazing but there is one problem, I have worked there for 3 years on the same salary. Its a private company and managed completely by my friend. I am getting like 400$ per month. But I want an increase in my salary.

Is it okay to ask for a rise in my salary?

Comment: Of course it's ok. And welcome to the Workplace. What country do you work in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: @Dukeling No, its not a duplicate. Because its a different case, Owner of the company is my friend, because of that i am not getting a right way to let him know that i want increment in my salary. Thanks.

Comment: @rath Pakistan.

Comment: If you're working for him then he's no longer your friend.

Comment: Sana Asghar, the point here is that you need to separate your friendship from your employment relationship. He is your boss. You should treat this like any other situation with a boss.

Comment: On the other hand, if friendship matters, the owner should look favorably on giving a raise to a friend.  If friendship doesn't go both ways, well, you can always try https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Here's the language you need:

> "Steve, $400 a month is not enough nowadays. Starting on the 1st, I'm thinking $1200 a month.  Can you give me your thoughts? What sort of figure would work for you?

I'll completely explain the communications secrets here:

There are three things you need to know, and indeed three things to say:

> "Steve, $400 a month is not enough nowadays.

1. Notice it is a *statement* with *no* reasons given.  Never, ever, give reasons.  Make statements.

> Starting on the 1st, I'm thinking $1200 a month.

2. When you state how much you want, always - always - include a *specific date*, refer to the specific cheque or transfer.

> Can you give me your thoughts? What sort of figure would work for you?

3. Always finish with a *question*. This is a magic trick of negotiations and discussions.

"How should I ask for an increment in my salary?"  You now have the answer!  Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand why you're suggesting to not give reasons. And, at any rate, you basically gave one: "$400 a month is not enough nowadays."

Comment: hi @dwizum !  in negotiations if you state a reason, it just opens the door for talk-talk from the other party about why that particular reason is incorrect.  State your price.

Comment: Ok - so the employer is supposed to give you a raise simply because you asked? With zero justification or explanation? That sounds like a recipe for failure, and I can't find any significant research or expert recommendation that backs that approach. Do you know of any? I get your point, and I understand it's application to "negotiation" in the generic sense, I just think your approach is a bit skewed when it comes to asking for a raise.

Comment: @Fattie Maybe you shouldn't state why you want a raise, but it is never a bad idea to state what they would gain by giving you a raise

Answer (score 4):

Here are some steps to take *before* starting negotiations to increase your chance of success.

**Ask for Manager’s Feedback Early**

Before mentioning the idea of a raise, confirm how the company sees your job performance. Ask your manager for feedback on your current performance, or on a recent project. This will help you gauge the right time to begin negotiation. It will also help you build and present a stronger case.

**Document Success**

Before discussing salary list examples of how you added value to the company. Take a look at look at annual report or mission statements to tie back to company goals. Create slides or a chart showing where you added value, so both parties agree on the facts.

**Approach as Conversation**

Approaching salary negotiation as an open conversation about perform and and job requirement can give you insight to the company’s process, while increasing your chances of success.

**Meet with Manager to Give Heads Up**

No one likes to be caught off guard, this can lower your chance of success. Before beginning negotiations make an meeting appointment with your manager to let them know you plan on asking for a raise. You can get early feedback and you will give them time to start considering the opportunity, without the added pressure of time constraints.

**Find Your Market Value**

Know your market value for your skills and experience. Check your company’s current job description for your role, compare your skills against the job requirements. Also, what additional duties are you prepared to take on?

When you’re ready to negotiate, use [these real life examples](https://bit.ly/2zuWsOP) from actual hiring managers.

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners for links on Stack Exchange. The *only* valid reason to use them is when you need to save characters. You *don't* need to do that in questions or answers here. Using a URL shortener makes the link, and your post, look like spam or otherwise nefarious (e.g. that the link goes to a spam site, infected download, or a site that contains viruses/trojans, etc.)